# Create HTML table with fixed width columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a table to have fixed width but dynamic height because content may be of various length. Here is an example:

[image]

I have fixed width but the content is overlapping. What I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
<table width="60%" align='center' cellpadding='2' 
        cellspacing='2' border='2' style='table-layout:fixed'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my css:

```
table{
font-size:12px;
}

table td{
    padding:5px; height:auto;
    background:#f6f6f6;
}

table thead tr th{
    background:#d7dbe2; 
}
```

Any ideas how to make the height dynamic?

Comment: what behavior do you want when the content exceeds the width of a cell column? a: Stretch the cell, or b: Hide the extra content? (e.g. if your contents contains a large string value with no spaces or other punctuation to wrap on)

Comment: a: stretch the cell but only in height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table td{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

This worked for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are no `'breaking points'` (e.g. spaces) in the text. So the text cannot be broke into mulitple lines. One solution would be to add `&shy;` at the places the text may break.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by your use of `table-layout: fixed` - I would suggest putting `style="width: 150px;"` in each of the `<th>` tags and removing the `table-layout`

Answer (score 0):

The `<th>` width tends to supersede `<td>` widths. So simply applying a width to the `<th>` (as Kolink said) should solve your overflow problem.

```
table thead tr th{
    width:120px; 
}
```